# c# polymorphism without method overloading (for a webmethod)

Tags: c#

Okay, so I realised after writing some overloaded methods that webmethods can't be overloaded (by realised I mean VS  threw a paddy and wouldn't allow me to update the service references). I have tried to get around that like this:

```
    public string DoPing<T>(T IP)
    {

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        { 
            return DoPingString(IP);
        }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(IPAddress))
        {
            return DoPingIP(IP);
        }
        throw new Exception("Programmer Error");
    }
```

But I'm getting a cannot convert from T to string/Ipadress error when I call the respective (renamed) methods. 
Can someone explain why it doesn't work, and possibly either fix it or give me an alternate solution?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Good point, generics are probably overkill (I tried for another solution and failed before trying this).
DoPingString(string String) and DoPingIP(IPAdress Address) are the signatures.
I will give the tick to the closest answer tomorrow. I solved the problem in a separate way.

Comment: XML Web Services right? if overload is not supported how come you guess generics are supported? To my knowledge you really need to create different method signatures, meaning different method names and no generics...

Comment: Also, the generics here gives no particular benefit over using an `object` argument, really.

Comment: Show the signature of DoPingString and DoPingIP please.

Comment: You can't have generic parameters in a web method. Everything is sent as strings, so the framework has to know the type that you want. It can't guess what data type it could possibly convert the string to.

Comment: You can't expose generics in web services but you can use `WebMethodAttribute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using generics the way it was intended. The compiler has no idea what type T is, so it won't just let you implicitly or explicitly cast to String or IPAddress. 
Here's a version that works:

```
    public string DoPing<T>(T IP)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return DoPingString((String)Convert.ChangeType(IP, typeof(String)));
        }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(IPAddress))
        {
            return DoPingIP((IPAddress)Convert.ChangeType(IP, typeof(IPAddress)));
        }
        throw new Exception("Programmer Error");
    }
```

However, since you're using generics with no constraint, you gain no benefit from the generic implementation. Why not just take an object?

```
public string DoPing(Object IP)
{
    if (IP.GetType() == typeof(string))
    {
        return DoPingString((String)IP);
    }
    if (IP.GetType() == typeof(IPAddress))
    {
        return DoPingIP((IPAddress)IP);
    }
    throw new Exception("Programmer Error");
}
```

Of course, the simpler and easier approach would be to simply overload your function, i.e.:

```
public string DoPing(string IP)
{
    return DoPingString(IP);
}
public string DoPing(IPAddress IP)
{
    return DoPingIP(IP);
}
```

Comment: The OP said that he tried overloading first, but it didn't work with his RPC library.

Comment: Your second answer was similar to what I eventually did.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `WebMethodAttribute` :

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "DoPingIPAddress")]
public string DoPing(IPAddress ip) { }

[WebMethod(MessageName = "DoPingString")]
public string DoPing(string ip) { }
```

But from the client side, you'll have two different methods : it's web services/SOAP constraints.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute_members%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: The idea was to use one function from the client side to multiple functions on the server side. Thank you though, I have learnt something new.

Comment: Ok, so I'm afraid you can't achieve this with web services. Maybe using WCF you can find something that matches requirement :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Convert.ChangeType` method then cast as usual:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
{ 
    return DoPingString((string)Convert.ChangeType(IP, typeof(string)));
}
if (typeof(T) == typeof(IPAddress))
{
   return DoPingIP((IPAddress)Convert.ChangeType(IP, typeof(IPAddress)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the `KnownTypeAttribute` available in WCF. But seeing as you can't use that here and you definitely want only one method then I think the only way is to just offer two parameters.  Just add some validation to check for nulls and pass them on to your private helper methods.

```
[WebMethod] 
public string DoPing(string ipString, IPAddress ipAdress)
{
    if(ipString != null)
    {
        DoPing(ipString);
    }
    if(ipAdress != null)
    {
        DoPing(ipAdress);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would better do this:

```
public string DoPing(IPAddress ip)
{
    ...logic...
}

public string DoPing(String ip)
{
    ...logic...
}
```

Try to avoid unnecessary patterns and templates.

Comment: That looks pretty similar to overloading. Are you sure you read the question?